# Java error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the error I am getting and I do not know why.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

I thought it was the array list, but when I tried counter + 1 it didn't work either.

Comment: `size of list` is smaller than the index being accessed, suppose `size is 1, index should be 0 only not 1`

Comment: did you debugged it?

Comment: Could you provide stack trace with exception? In which function do you get this exception?

Comment: Isn't it at dicedata.get(counter)? If so, please provide this method code

Comment: this is the function the issue occurs in. the method is above. dicedata is an arraylist.

Comment: can u share the full code ?

Comment: Can you please update what is the values for `NUMBER_OF_SIDES` and `diceData` , where they are initialized , etc?

Comment: Also, if you look at the stack dump you might see the class where the exception is thrown which is a clear indication of whether this occurs with an array list or something else. Not posting all of the relevant information is (withheld).

Comment: I have posted the full class

Comment: Where is this called, maybe the issue is there? Seems like you are only passing in arraylist of `1` item to the Board constructor

Comment: @Anand yea the arraylist size is 1, why is this, how do I fix it..

Comment: Which exact line the errr occurs in?

Comment: We do not know. Its just giving this exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: You should be getting the stack trace, it would like something like - `(Board.java : <some number>)` , that some number is the line

Comment: My answer below and @AnandSKumar both cover why you are getting the exception. If you need further clarification then posting the class where you instantiate and add elements to boggleData is the only way we can help. Otherwise, please see JavaDoc tutorial on ArrayLists.

Comment: Did your issue get fixed?

Answer (score 0):

With the partial of code that you provided, it appears you only have one element in the `diceData` ArrayList. You need to have as many elements in the ArrayList as `NUMBER_OF_SIDES` for your loop to work without throwing the Exception.

You can check this by printing out `diceData.size()` to see if it is equal to or greater than NUMBER_OF_SIDES.

Answer (score 0):

your below code causes the problem--

```
   for (int col= 0; col < NUMBER_OF_SIDES; col++)
    { 
         int counter = 0;
        //Add each of the 6 letters to the die ArrayList representing 
        //the die letters by calling method addLetter in class Die 
        die.addLetter(diceData.get(counter).toString());
        counter++;
    }
```

The reason behind this is that,

your `diceData` arraylist reference is only instantiated but it didn't contained any value in it. i.e.`diceData` array list is empty.

So To avoid this situation do the following--

```
for (int col= 0; col < NUMBER_OF_SIDES; col++)
    { 
         int counter = 0;
        //Add each of the 6 letters to the die ArrayList representing 
        //the die letters by calling method addLetter in class Die 
        if(!diceData.isEmpty())
         {
        die.addLetter(diceData.get(counter).toString());
        counter++;
         }
        }
```

Also I am still not able to understand why you are always initializing and incrementing counter in above foor loop.? As I didn't see any use of that in your code.

Comment: According to his code, it is initialized to the passed in value in his constructor

Comment: diceData is not empty. The exception shows a size of 1 and it is initialized to the arrayList passed in as a parameter.

Comment: This does not fix it.